# Why does toggling one checkbox also toggle some others?

Tags: angular

I built a table component. User can select which columns he wants to see.

You can try it on StackBlitz. Doesn't look nice without all the SCSS, but it shows the same phenomenon. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-she4fk

At start, only three checkboxes are checked, and the appropriate columns are visible.

When I toggle any one checkbox, the column gets shown or hidden, **but** other checkboxes get checked/unchecked as well. The columns are shown correctly, but the checkboxes are completely wrong. I don't see the problem, especially because the table and the underlying array behave as expected!

For this example, I begin in `Frame 1` with the columns `First name`, `Sur name` and `Department` visible (and the corresponding checkboxes checked). Then I set the `Selection` checkbox: on-off-on. Every time, other checkboxes react (without the underlying array being changed).

I would like to understand why. And most importantly: How can I stop the other boxes from reacting?
(Maybe interesting sidenote: The pattern is reproducible. When I reload the app (F5) and select the `Selection` checkbox, I can always reproduce these exact same "Frames 1-4". So the behaviour of the other checkboxes is not random.)

[image: Changing "Selection" checkbox checks/unchecks other checkboxes]

Here is the code, pretty straight forward.

```
export class AppComponent  {
    fieldTitle: string[] = [];
    fieldVisibility: boolean[] = [];

    constructor()
    {
        this.fieldTitle[0] = 'Selection';
        this.fieldTitle[1] = 'Personal number';
        this.fieldTitle[2] = 'Salutation';
        this.fieldTitle[3] = 'First name';
        this.fieldTitle[4] = 'Last name';
        this.fieldTitle[5] = 'Department';
        this.fieldTitle[6] = 'Company';

        this.fieldVisibility[0] = false;
        this.fieldVisibility[1] = false;
        this.fieldVisibility[2] = false;
        this.fieldVisibility[3] = true;
        this.fieldVisibility[4] = true;
        this.fieldVisibility[5] = true;
        this.fieldVisibility[6] = false;
    }

    toggleVisibility(fieldIdx: number) {
        console.log(fieldIdx + ' BEFORE toggle: ' + JSON.stringify(this.fieldVisibility));
        this.fieldVisibility[fieldIdx] = !this.fieldVisibility[fieldIdx];
        console.log(fieldIdx + ' AFTER  toggle: ' + JSON.stringify(this.fieldVisibility));
    }

    isVisible(fieldIdx: number) {
        console.log(fieldIdx + ' is ' + (this.fieldVisibility[fieldIdx] ? 'visible' : 'hidden'));
        return this.fieldVisibility[fieldIdx];
    }
}
```

And the template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let visible of fieldVisibility; index as i;">
            <th *ngIf="visible">{{fieldTitle[i]}}</th>
        </ng-container>

        <th>
            <ul>
                <!-- solution: "let dummy of fieldTitle; index as i" -->
                <li *ngFor="let visible of fieldVisibility; index as i">
                    <label>
                        <input (change)="toggleVisibility(i)"
                              [checked]="isVisible(i)"
                              type="checkbox">
                        {{fieldTitle[i]}}
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the code in stackblitz ?

Comment: looks like this code  `(change)="fieldVisibility[i] = !fieldVisibility[i]"` is redundant . Could you please comment it and check it

Comment: @SatishPai You can find it at https://angular-obmnmw.stackblitz.io . When I remove the ``(change)`` then of course toggling one checkbox doesn't toggle any other. But also the corresponding table column doesn't get shown/hidden.

Comment: https://angular-obmnmw.stackblitz.io this link is the hosted one, I would like to work on the source code. Could you please provide the link of it ?

Comment: @SatishPai Ah, sorry. First time I use StackBlitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obmnmw  Seems to be pretty straightforward getting from the "hosted link" to the "edit link". :-)

Comment: Btw. using ``[(ngModel)]`` instead of ``(change)`` and ``[checked]`` leads to *almost* the same behaviour. (Slightly different checkboxes get cross-fired.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fieldTitle` array in the `*ngFor` instead of `fieldVisibility`. Like this:
`<ng-container *ngFor="let visible of fieldTitle; index as i">`

Comment: could you please tell me why this was happening ?

Comment: @Anarno Thank you, that works. However I would also be interested to learn *why* that makes a difference? Sure it makes sense not to change the array that ``*ngFor`` uses, *inside* of the loop. But then again, I'm not changing the array, I'm changing values inside of the array. I would argue, this *should* work--- and using ``fieldTitle`` instead *should not* make a difference. Well, it does. :-) But why?

Comment: The array is an object. If an object changed, the angular re-render the DOM. Never change mutable the objects. Or use `trackBy` whit an unique `id` property, and then the angular knows which rows changed, and re-renders only the changed rows.

Comment: See in the browser inspect, see the list in the DOM, and you will see how it works when u use `fieldVisibility` array.

Answer (score 1):

you can not iterate over the same element you want to change, if you iterate over

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let visible of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; let i=index">
```

You has no problen. Even if you decided has only an unique array like

```
fields=[
      {title: 'Selection',visibility:false},
        {title: 'Personal number',visibility:false},
        {title: 'Salutation',visibility:false},
        {title: 'First name',visibility:true},
        {title: 'Last name',visibility:true},
        {title: 'Department',visibility:true},
        {title: 'Company',visibility:false}
    ]
```

You can do

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields; index as i;">
    <th *ngIf="field.visibility">{{fieldTitle[i]}}</th>
</ng-container>
```

(see that we can use field.visibility and field.title)

And

```
<input [(ngModel)]="field.visibility"
    [name]="'fieldSelectId'+i" 
    class="form-check-input" [id]="'fieldSelect'+i" type="checkbox" >
```

In this case you don't violate the rule "can not iterate over an element you change" because you change the "propertie" of an object, no the object itself